# Can't access storage account

Tags: docker, azure-cli

When I run the following command on my host system, it works:

```
azure storage share create --account-name myaccount --account-key mykey myshare
```

But when I use the Docker Azure-CLI:

```
docker run -it microsoft/azure-cli
```

and execute the same command there, it fails:

```
info: Executing command storage share create
info: Creating storage file share myshare
error: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:8ce76eed-001a-0134-6355-3b8268000000
Time:2016-11-10T13:19:30.9105340Z
error: Error information has been recorded to /root/.azure/azure.err
error: storage share create command failed
```

I already tried different image-tags and also azure-cli images from other contributors, but same result.

Any ideas what's going on?

Edit:

`azure storage account list` -> works

`azure storage share list -a myshare -k mykey` -> doesn't work (same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong datetime inside my container because of that issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/72